rephrase the condition in a more geometric form
Define $A$ as $n\times 2$ matrix. The inner product of every pair of two rows of $A$ satisfies $$a\geq A_{i,:}\cdot A_{j,:}\geq b$$ for $\forall i,j\in[n]$.
My question is, how to rephrase this condition by saying that $A$ belongs to a certain geometric object?
For example, maybe a polytope, etc?
What I tried is to write
$$AA^T$$
then this is a $n\times n$ matrix, with element $(AA^T)_{ij}=A_{i,:}\cdot A_{j,:}$, then the condition can be written as
$$\|AA^T\|_\infty\leq a$$ $$\|-AA^T\|_\infty\leq -b$$
But I don't know whether there is a simpler way.
